# getting data from a (n)curses form

Tags: ncurses, curses

I trying to use the forms extension in an (n)curses application and am having trouble to retrieve the entered data to process.  The forms documentation mentions the function:

```
char *field_buffer(FIELD *field,          /* field to query */
                   int bufindex);         /* number of buffer to query */
```

but then warns:

> Calling field_buffer() on a field not currently selected for input
>   will return a correct value. Calling field_buffer() on a field that is
>   currently selected for input may not necessarily give a correct field
>   buffer value, because entered data isn't necessarily copied to buffer
>   zero before the exit validation check. To guarantee that the returned
>   buffer value reflects on-screen reality, call field_buffer() either
>   (1) in the field's exit validation check routine, (2) from the field's
>   or form's initialization or termination hooks, or (3) just after a
>   REQ_VALIDATION request has been processed by the forms driver.

This indeed appears to be the case.

My scenario is:

1. create form and fields
2. process user input
3. when Enter is hit, process form data and exit form

In accordance with the documentation, retrieving the buffer data from the non-selected fields is correct, but the data from the final field is not (because that field is still selected and not terminated).

I can't see from the documentation how to force termination of the field (or forcing the update of the buffer contents).

Comment: Without some sample program which demonstrates the behavior, it is hard to give advice.  The ncurses sources have several test-programs which use the form library.

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to invoke

```
form_driver(form, REQ_VALIDATION);
```

before processing the form content. This will also validate the current field and commit its content to the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same thing right now and just figured out I can just focus next field in the form before getting values via field_buffer. So when enter is pressed I call form_driver(form, REQ_NEXT_FIELD); and then buffer for current active field is correctly updated when I access the value with field_buffer().